# OpenCV C++ cannot open video unless program is run as root

Tags: c++, linux, opencv

I'm trying to open a video file in Opencv C++, but it doesn't work in a weird way.
I'm on Fedora, and opencv is installed through dnf's opencv-devel package.

Here is the test code I'm using :

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/videoio/videoio.hpp>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::string imagePath = "/home/me/picture.png";
    
    cv::Mat image = cv::imread(imagePath);
    
    std::cout << image << std::endl;
    
    std::string videoPath = "/home/me/video.mp4";
    
    cv::VideoCapture cap{ videoPath };
    
    if(!cap.isOpened())
    {
        std::cout << "Error while opening video" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    
    cv::Mat startFrame;
    cap >> startFrame;
    
    std::cout << startFrame;
    
    cap.release();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Then, I Compile it with the libraries:

```
g++ -c -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -I/usr/include/opencv4/ -o dist/obj/main.o src/main.cpp
g++ -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_videoio dist/obj/main.o -o dist/bin/main
```

And when I run it, the image is read fine, but the video shows an error.
However, when I run it as sudo, the video reads just fine. I searched around a lot and couldn't find someone with a similar problem, so I'm posting this here.

Also, the python version works fine, so it shouldn't<sup>tm</sup> be a codec problem.

Comment: could you check permissions on the shared libs it is using?  Could also have something to do with the environment...

Comment: You can also check the permissions on the files you're trying to read.

Comment: All shared libs have permission 755, so there should be no problem with them, the video has permission 777, and I tried running it in my home directory and got the same result, I'm kind of at a loss here...

Comment: try to construct with ```cv::VideoCapture cap(videoPath, cv::CAP_FFMPEG);```. Also try using ```cap.getBackendName();``` to see if tghere's something wrong with your backend api.

Comment: It seems compiling from source and enabling gstreamer did the trick, but I'm still kinda weirded out, as it works fine on another computer with the same libraries...